# Pushing and Pulling with Git

Tags: git, github

I created a new local branch from my master branch, named V_2. When I commit my changes and push them to origin, they get pushed to origin/V_2. 
If I now checkout to my master branch and try to pull the changes it thinks that the master branch is already up-to-date as it tries to pull from origin/master.

Is there a way to just have one origin, where everything gets pushed to or am I missing something fundamental of git? I am really new to git and it seems like i miss something.

Comment: Pulling does not merge branches into other branches. Read the git book, and look for merge and rebase.

Answer (score 1):

Since you made changes to a new branch (something other than master), if you want the changes in master - you need to merge them.

```
$ git merge V_2
```

When you `$ git pull`, it does a pull on the currently checked out branch (assuming the upstream is set correctly) unless explicitly stated. e.g.: `$ git pull origin <branch>`

> Is there a way to just have one origin

"Origin" is simply a name for the remote.

> where everything gets pushed to or am I missing something fundamental of git?

I think you are missing the "distributed" nature of git.  Branching is very cheap in git.  create branches for things, and merge them in when done.

Answer (score 1):

Well if **you didn't do any changes in master** (your description seems that you didn't) then there obviously are no changes. You did changes to another branch: V_2.

If you want to **include the changes made on V_2 into master**, you need to *merge* the V_2 branch into master branch. To do that:

1. Checkout master: `git checkout master`
2. Make sure your local master branch is up-to-date with remote master: `git pull`
3. Merge V_2 into master: `git merge V_2`

I've answered your question, but it seems you lack some basic understanding of GIT. I would advise you to read some good tutorials. It is important to understand how GIT works as it's a **distributed system** and it may be counter-intuitive at first.

The most important thing to remember is that you always have two "versions" of each branch. A local one (on your machine) and a remote one (GIT server - in your case, by the name of *origin*). The remote one is created when you push your local branch to the server for the first time. Those two branches (local and remote), can at any time be in different states, so it is important to always make sure you have an up-to-date state of your local branch before you perform any operations with it. That's what you use *pull* for.